# ember cli app with bootstrap drop down menu immediately closes on mouse release

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, ember-cli

I have only recently started using ember and I wanted to include bootstrap. I added bootstrap via bower: `bower install --save bootstrap` then added the following into my ember-cli-build.js file:

```
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js');
```

All appears to be working, but when I added a drop down menu, clicking on the menu expands as expected, but then immediately closes on mouse release - I.e. a single click looks like nothing happens, but if you click and hold the menu appears and then disappears as soon as you release the button. If I use the tab keys to tab to the menu and then hit the down arrow the drop down menu appears too. I suspect it has something to do with jquery, as the debugger jumps into jquery.js and somewhere in there the menu closes but I am not proficient enough to figure out what is going on...

here is my bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ember-mm-phone-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "1.13.3",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.3",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-data": "1.13.5",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.5",
    "ember-qunit": "0.4.1",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.18",
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.0",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1",
    "ember-simple-auth": "0.8.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ember-localstorage-adapter": "0.5.4"
  }
}
```

Here is the drop down menu:

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Account <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>{{link-to 'Profile' 'user'}}</li>
            <li>{{link-to 'Settings' 'application'}}</li>
            <li>{{link-to 'Terms and Conditions' 'application'}}</li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li>
              <a {{ action 'invalidateSession' }}>Logout</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you read the [Bootstrap guide on dropdown menus](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage), it says that the Javascript adds the `open` class to the element. The problem with that is Ember wants to manage the DOM itself, it doesn't want any third party libraries doing it. So when Bootstrap adds a class to the DOM, it's likely going to be overwritten the next time Ember updates the DOM.

There are a few potential solutions to this depending on your use case. You could wrap the dropdown in a component, but that might be overkill. The simplest method would be to use Ember's click events instead of calling `$(element).dropdown()`.

```
<li class="dropdown {{if dropdownOpen 'open'}}">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" {{action 'toggleDropdown'}}>
    Account <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>{{link-to 'Profile' 'user'}}</li>
    <li>{{link-to 'Settings' 'application'}}</li>
    <li>{{link-to 'Terms and Conditions' 'application'}}</li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>
      <a {{ action 'invalidateSession' }}>Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Notice the condition class on the `li` and the action on the `a`. Now, in your controller, do this:

```
dropdownOpen: false,

actions: {
    toggleDropdown() {
        this.toggleProperty('dropdownOpen');
    }
}
```

That will add and remove the `open` class for you, avoiding the need for the Bootstrap Javascript plugin. If that doesn't cover all of your bases, you may want to look into wrapping the dropdown in a [component](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/components/). Wrapping in a component will require a little more work though. There's also some Ember Bootstrap projects out there, but I don't know how well they work.

Short story long: it's not working for you because Ember is overwriting the changes to the DOM that Bootstrap is making. You'll need a way to integrate the two.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helped point in the right direction for some other questions I had, but not for this specific issue unfortunately. There must have been something else happening as a result of other bower installs I had done this morning because my machine gradually ground to a halt about an hour after posting this question. I had to reboot and then the drop down menu magically starting working! Very frustrating when you spend several hours on an issue and get it solved by a reboot. Thanks again for your insights.

Comment: I would say that even if this wasn't your issue now, it certainly could become an issue in the future. I wouldn't say you have to change any code yet, but just be aware of the potential issues so you know what to look for if they happen.

Comment: It fixed my similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

There must have been something else happening as a result of other bower installs I had done this morning because my machine gradually ground to a halt about an hour after posting this question. I had to reboot and then the drop down menu magically starting working! Very frustrating when you spend several hours on an issue and it it solved by a reboot.